# Passing data over views

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a navigation based view and the data entered in a view that is lower down in the hierarchy is then to be shown in a table-view in the root-view. How do I pass data entered in a subview to a superview??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is several ways to do that.
You can create a singleton class which provide data to your UIViewControllers: [Creating a Singleton Instance](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html)

Or you can use [UINavigationControllerDelegate Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UINavigationControllerDelegate) which include method called before and after UIViewController push.